# In css how to display multiple divs?

Tags: html, css

In my project I want to display the text as like below:--

```
  Title
Name  Date
details
```

But I am getting :--

```
  Title
Namedetails
  Date
```

Here is my jsfiddle link  :-[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/76gr4k4w/1/)

Where I have problem??

Comment: float:left is causing the issue.

Comment: Also be more specific what are trying to achieve with dependency.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/76gr4k4w/5/) to see result.

Here are my changes:

```
.A > div{
    margin-right: 5px;
}

#title{
    font-size: 100%;
}
#details{
    font-size:100%;
    float: left;
    clear: both;
    display: inline-block;
}

#block1 {
  float: left;
  display: block;

}

#block2 {
    float: left;
    clear: right;
}
```

You have added `#title` twice, I replaces it with `details` here and added css rules above:

```
<div id= "details">
     <a>details</a>
</div>
```

And for an advice, use general css rules that you apply to multiple elements into single class and add that class to all your elements. Do not duplicate css rules to much.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it's not necessary to add a `clear: left` when you already added a `float: left` to that same element. Instead, add a `clear: both` to the `#title` so it will stack at the bottom of all elements:

```
#title {
  font-size: 100%;
  clear: both;
}
#block1 {
  float: left;
  display: block;
}
#block2 {
  float: left;
  display: block;
}
.A {
  position: relative;
  margin: 40px 0;
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  background: #eee;
}
.A:after {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  background: #c00;
  height: 29px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -29px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
.A div{
    padding:2px;
}
#title{
    font-size:100%;
}

#block1 {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;

}

#block2 {

 display: inline-block;
clear:left;
}
.A {
    position: relative;
    margin: 40px 0;
    height: 100px;
    width: 200px;
    background: #eee;
}

.A:after {
    content: " ";
    display: block;
    background: #c00;
    height: 29px;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -29px;
}
```

**[Demo Here](http://jsfiddle.net/76gr4k4w/14/)**

**OR**

I have simplified your css code.

Use this

```
#title{
    font-size:100%;
}

#block1 , #block2{

  display: inline-block;

}


.A {
    position: relative;
    margin: 40px 0;
    height: 100px;
    width: 200px;
    background: #eee;
}

.A:after {
    content: " ";
    display: block;
    background: #c00;
    height: 29px;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -29px;
}
```

**[Demo Here](http://jsfiddle.net/76gr4k4w/15/)**